# Почему в зависимости от того, где указать правило css оно выполняется или нет?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

У меня несколько вопросов:

1) на счёт header.

2) почему не работает правило для класса each_2nd?

3)  почему порядок указания правил css влияет на их выполнение? Например, если указание правил для header поставить перед указанием для div.container, то заработают правила для header, но перестанут работать для h1. А иначе(если вернуть как было) будут работать для h1 и не будут работать для  header :/

И, да, с такими проблемами сталкиваюсь впервые. Раньше вроде как порядок написания правил не влиял ни на что, а сейчас такая хрень.

```css
body {
    background-color: #000;
}
/*Если header стоит тут, то всё ок*/
header {
    display: block;
    
    color: lightblue;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
div.container {
    background-color: #e5e8c0;
    height: 550px;
}
div.table {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
a:hover {
    color: green;
}
a:active {
    color:darkgreen;
}
a:visited {
    color: red;
}
/*Если header тут, то не работает.*/
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;

}
tr.header {
    background-color: khaki;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    background-color: #000;
}
td, th {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    
}
th {
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
td {
    background-color: #aaa;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
}
th.name {
    /*height: 20px;*/
}
tr.each_2nd {
    background-color: darkgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <header>
  <h1>Раздел продажи инструментов</h1>
 </header>
 <div class="content">
  <div class="table">
   <table>
    <tr class="header">
     <th class="name" width="300">Название</th>
     <th width="300">Производитель</th>
     <th width="250">Цена</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Пианино</td>
     <td>Piano Masters</td>
     <td>$100 000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="each_2nd">
     <td>Рояль</td>
     <td>Piano Fanatics</td>
     <td>$150 000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Клавинет</td>
     <td>Clavinet Idiots 24/7 Idiots</td>
     <td>$1</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: «порядок написания правил не влиял» — всегда влиял, об этом написано в любом учебнике по html/css

Comment: «почему не работает правило для класса each_2nd?» — очень даже работает, `<tr class="each_2nd">` имеет тёмно-зелёный цвет. Только вот внутри этого `tr` лежат элементы `td`, имеющие `background-color: #aaa;` — и они просто перекрывают своим серым фоном тёмно-зелёный цвет под ними

Comment: @andreymal автор книги, которую я сейчас читаю видимо забыл написать об этом) Можете сказать в каком порядке их надо писать?

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/kaskadirovanie

Comment: Но в вашем случае порядок не имеет значения, и проблему из пункта 3 повторить не удаётся: я переставлял стили для header и туда, и сюда, но страница выглядит во всех случаях одинаково и все стили работают. Покажите пример, который у вас не работает

Comment: Кстати, ваши стили содержат синтаксическую ошибку: после комментария `/*Если header тут, то не работает.*/` у вас стоит закрывающая скобка, которая ничего не закрывает

Comment: @andreymal лооол! Это из-за лишней фигурной скобки))

Comment: @andreymal да да да я заметил)

Comment: Всё! Теперь всё работает!) Спасибо за ответы!)